# The express command gives an error after global install "express not recognized"

Tags: node.js, express

I have tried all the solutions that are provided here but none seems to work.
The first time when I installed express, I run npx express-generator and after the install finished I run express command but the error appeared so I searched for a solution here on Stack Overflow, and tried all the other commands:

- npm install -g express-generator
- npm install -g express
- npm install express-generator -g
- npm install -g express-generator@3

```
C:\Users\user>npx express-generator
npx: installed 10 in 4.888s

  warning: the default view engine will not be jade in future releases
  warning: use `--view=jade' or `--help' for additional options

destination is not empty, continue? [y/N] y

   create : public\
   create : public\javascripts\
   create : public\images\
   create : public\stylesheets\
   create : public\stylesheets\style.css
   create : routes\
   create : routes\index.js
   create : routes\users.js
   create : views\
   create : views\error.jade
   create : views\index.jade
   create : views\layout.jade
   create : app.js
   create : package.json
   create : bin\
   create : bin\www

   install dependencies:
     > npm install

   run the app:
     > SET DEBUG=user:* & npm start


C:\Users\user>express
'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But none of them worked, I kept getting the same error.
What could be the problem?

Comment: I still get the same error when I try running angular commands.

C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\htdocs\project-zero\appDir>ng new cfe-app
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: For angular, please check your environment variable and see that it points to the `ng` bin file. As for express,it is a module that gives you a factory function to create new instances of express servers. I don't think you can execute it like a command.